# Excel VBA Run-time error '1004': "Application-defined or object-defined error" when assigning Range.Value Property

Tags: excel, vba, excel-2016

OK, I've seen a lot of similar questions on here, but in all the ones I found, either there wasn't an answer, or it wasn't the same as my situation and didn't apply, or I tried the solution and it didn't work for me.

Issue is, in my code snippet below, I am getting "Run-time error '1004': Application-defined or object-defined error assigning Range.Value Property"

I do have `Option Explicit` set.

`R`, `NR`, and `RungTopRow` are all declared as integer types earlier in the code. `CommentRow` is also an integer (only ever equal to 0 or 1, declared as an integer rather than Boolean because I use the 0 or 1 as a multiplier in equations). `CurrentCell` is declared as type Range. `LadderSheet` is of type `Worksheet` set to a specific worksheet in my Excel file. I have used `LadderSheet` numerous other times in my program without any issues. `RowSize` is a defined constant equal to 6. `thatRung` is a class variable of type `Rung` that I have defined. `CommentText` is a public variable that is declared as part of the `Rung` Class. I have tried declaring `CommentText` as a string and defining it as a variant. I get the same error either way. `Option Explicit` is also set in the `Rung` Class Module.

NR is the number of Rungs in a ladder logic source that I'm using. This is only part of my code, additionally I have code to exit the program if `RungTopRow` ever *equals or exceeds* the maximum number of rows allowed by excel by comparing to a defined `Const LastXLRow = 1048576`.

Regardless, when I insert a breakpoint, I find that I'm getting the error on a value of `RungTopRow` = 3. So, I'm definitely not exceeding the maximum row.

Everything I've bundled into {Other Code Here} can run without error when I comment the below section out. Actually everything runs otherwise as expected if I comment out the .value assignment statement.

```
    For R = 0 To NR
        
    If R = 0 And CommentRow Then
        With LadderSheet.Range("C" & CStr(RungTopRow + 1) & ":P" & CStr(RungTopRow + RowSize - 1))
            .MergeCells = True
            .ShrinkToFit = False
            .WrapText = True
        End With
         Set CurrentCell = LadderSheet.Cells(RungTopRow + 1, 3)
        'this line keeps giving an application defined error
        CurrentCell.Value = thatRung.CommentText

    End If

    ... {Other Code Here} ...

    Next R
```

First I tried

```
LadderSheet.Cells(RungTopRow + 1, 3).Value = thatRung.CommentText
```

I replaced LadderSheet.Cells(RungTopRow, 3) with CurrentCell as that worked for me in another similar situation, but for some reason isn't working here.

I have also tried

```
currentComment = thatRung.CommentText
currentCell.Value = currentComment
```

With `currentComment` and `thatRung.CommentText` declared as strings. I get the same error, triggering on the assignment statement of `currentCell.Value` , so it is not due to the definition of `thatRung.CommentText`

Note that if I directly assign it to a literal string as follows:

```
CurrentCell.Value = "hello"
```

or as follows:

```
currentComment = "hello"
currentCell.Value = currentComment
```

It executes without issue. Of course, I don't get the text I actually want in that case. I need the text stored in `thatRung.CommentText` to go into the cell defined by the range `CurrentCell`.

**Update**
The Rung Class is too big to post here, but the only place where `CommentText` is mentioned is in the delcarations as follows:

```
Option Explicit
'These values are directly defined
Public Number As Integer
Public NumBranches As Integer
Public RungType As String
Public CommentText As String 'Neither string nor variant working
Public RungText As String

'These values will need to be calculated
Private Branches() As Branch
Private Items() As Item
Private ItemsEmpty As Boolean
Private CommandsEmpty As Boolean
Private InputsEmpty As Boolean
Private OutputsEmpty As Boolean
Private BranchesEmpty As Boolean

Const maxItemsperRow = 4 'Make sure other modules have same value in constant
```

Perhaps also relevant are places where `CommentText` is manipulated prior to the code I posted above in the following line in my main module code (ImportL5x):

```
thisRung.CommentText = thisRung.CommentText & ThatXMLTag.Contents
```

The code I posted is in a subroutine called `DrawRung` and `thisRung` is passed to `DrawRung` as an argument:

```
DrawRung thisRung
```

And DrawRung is defined with thatRung:

```
Public Sub DrawRung(thatRung As Rung)
```

`ThatXMLTag` is another custom class I defined called `XMLTag`. `Contents` is also a string.

This is all of the code for the `XMLTag` class (it is only declarations right now, everything is assigned externally in another module):

```
Option Explicit

Public Enum XMLType
   XMLStart = 0 'No starting /, no ! data
   XMLContent = 1 'Starting !
   XMLStop = 2 'Starting /
   XMLUnknown = 3 'Anything else
End Enum
Public Name As String
Public Contents As String
Public TagType As XMLType
```

Comment: It does sound like your custom class `Rung` is the issue somehow. It would help if you could post it and/or create a minimal class with ONLY that variable or property.

Comment: What's the value of thatrung.commentText when you get the error?

Comment: Updates Posted in response to the first two comments.

Comment: @NicholasHunter it's a very long text string that contains proprietary information I can't post. It happens to have 4 carriage return + newline character combos and about 20 characters in each of the 5 lines. All other characters are "=","-","_","." or alphanumeric.

Comment: @AutomateThis I just tried your suggestion. I still get the same error.

Comment: OK but it does have a value, right? Because that terror message usually means either CurrentCell or thatRung is Nothing. If that's not the case then I got nothing.

Comment: Re _it's a very long text string_ How long is "very long"? Text in a cell has a limit of 32,767 characters

Comment: @chrisneilsen "only" a few hundred characters in this case

Comment: Does `CurrentCell.Value = "'" & thatRung.CommentText` work ?  If what you're assigning looks like a formula then Excel might choke on it.  You can also try formatting the cell as Text before assigning the value.

Comment: You mention both `thatRung` and `thisRung`.  Is it a simple variable name typo?  Have you examined the value of the string when you get the error? (and checked it's length just to be sure)

Comment: @chrisneilsen No typo. In the context of the module `ImportL5x` it's `thisRung` in the context of `DrawRung` it's `thatRung`. It's passed from `ImportL5x` to `DrawRung` with the subroutine call I show in the update to the question. `ImportL5x` passes `thisrung` to `DrawRung` and `DrawRung` assigns it to `thatRung`

Comment: @TimWilliams thank you for the suggestion. It does work when I add "'"... but that, of course doesn't give me what I want. But thanks to your suggestion I figured it out. If I add ANYTHING to it, it works. I realize now I never initialized `thisRung.CommentText`, so when I executed `thisRung.CommentText = thisRung.CommentText & ThatXMLTag.Contents` it was doing `nothing` & `ThatXMLTag.Contents`. I would have thought `nothing` & something = something, and when I check my variables it shows something - but if I initialize `CommentText = " "` in a `class_initialize` sub in my Rung class, it works

Comment: Hmmm... weird. If I concatenate something & `nothing` there's no problem, but if I concatenate `nothing` & something there's an issue. Makes me wonder how VBA stores strings and if there's a null character stored at the beginning when you concatenate `nothing` & something and only if that null character is FIRST, does it choke on it.

Comment: `thisRung.CommentText` would default to an empty string, since that's the default value for String-typed variables.  It would not be `Nothing` - that's for object-typed variables.

Comment: @TimWilliams yep, I understand that. What I don't get is why I still have an issue when I concatenate `nothing` with something - and only if I concatenate `nothing` first. I mean, bad programming practice to not initialize on my part, but still strange behavior.

Comment: @Trashman when you say `nothing`, I guess you don't mean the object `Nothing` (that Tim refers to), because `SomeString = Nothing & "SomeText"` throws a compile error. Once again, have you examined the value of the string when you get the error? Given your last comments, especially the first character (eg with `Debug.Print Asc(Left(thatRung.CommentText, 1))`)

Comment: There is no `Nothing` involved here: if either `CommentText` or `Contents` are not initialized they would just be empty strings. There are no issues related to concatenating empty strings. Your real issue is likely that Excel thinks you're trying to assign a (broken) formula to the cell's `Value` property.

Comment: Sorry for the incorrect use of `nothing` and misreading the previous comment. I think you have a point on the broken formula, @TimWilliams as the first comment starts with a separator of ============. Since it begins with `=` it thinks its a formula and won't let me use it, so I have to put *some* kind of character before the first '=' or it throws this error. It makes sense to use ' now.

Comment: @TimWilliams could you post an answer based on your earlier comments so I can accept it and upvote it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When assigning something to an Excel cell - even when explicitly using the `Value` and not the `Formula`/`FormulaR1C1`/etc property - Excel will attempt to parse the cell content as a formula if it "looks" like it might be a formula.

For example, if the cell content begins with "=" Excel will try to parse the content as a formula, and if that fails will generate the type of run-time error you're describing.