# Excel VBA: "Application-defined or object-defined error" when writing to a cell

Tags: excel, vba, range, runtime-error

Environment: Excel v 2108 under Windows 11 Pro 64

The Internet has a lot about the "Application-defined or object-defined error" in Excel VBA. Even StackOverflow has many Q&As about it, such as [2013](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17980854/vba-runtime-error-1004-application-defined-or-object-defined-error-when-select), [2016](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40353757/cells-value-application-or-object-defined-error), [2018](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50354675/excel-vba-error-1004-application-defined-or-object-defined-error), [2021](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67307441/excel-vba-run-time-error-1004-application-defined-or-object-defined-error-w) and [2022](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74553406/excel-vba-run-time-error-1004-application-defined-or-object-defined-error-not-s), none marked as duplicates. The causes have been indicated as attempting to address a cell that doesn't exist (I don't know why that wouldn't be subscript-out-of-range instead), addressing a worksheet that is not active or that VBA doesn't recognize, attempting to write to a protected worksheet or to locked cells, and many other causes, none of which apply to my situation.

I have a workbook in which VBA writes extensively to its cells. But when I made some modifications, those writes brought up the "Application-defined or object-defined error". The original workbook still works, but new versions are not able to write to cells.

To check what's going on, I created a new workbook, in which I inserted a module with the following contents:

```
Function test(sInput As String) As String

MsgBox (Worksheets("sheet1").Range("A1").Value)

On Error Resume Next
Worksheets("sheet1").Range("B1").Value = "there"
If (Err.Number > 0) Then MsgBox ("Error " & Err.Number & ": " & Err.Description)

test = "Done " & sInput

End Function
```

Then I put the following contents in the worksheet:
[image]

In the function, the first `MsgBox()` tests that I can address a range in `sheet1`. The function then attempts to write to a cell. In the worksheet, I call the function from cell `A2`, referring to the contents of cell `A3`.

I saved the workbook and rebooted the computer to ensure there wasn't an OS cause of the problem. Then I opened the workbook, selected cell `A3` and typed "b" there:

[image]

When I press `Enter`, I get the first message box, showing that VBA understood my reference to a cell in the sheet:

[image]

But when I click "OK" in the message box, the function attempts to write to another cell in the sheet, and I get the "Application ..." error:

[image]

When I click "OK" in the error message box, the function concludes:

[image]

To address one possible cause of the problem, the next two images show that the entire sheet is not locked and that the sheet and workbook are not protected. (If they were protected, the icon labels would say "Unprotect" instead of "Protect".)

[image]
[image]

So what could be causing this error that is preventing me from writing to cells in the sheet?

Comment: User Defined Functions called from a cell are very limited in what they can do. They are meant to return a value (or values) to the calling cell, not to modify cells. See [limitations of custom functions](https://support.microsoft.com/en-au/topic/description-of-limitations-of-custom-functions-in-excel-f2f0ce5d-8ea5-6ce7-fddc-79d36192b7a1).